# Expand view from within a ScrollView to full screen

Tags: android, layout, android-videoview, expand, layoutparams

What I have is a ConstraintLayout, which contains a ScrollView as one of its children. Inside this scrollview there is a LinearLayout containing all the components in the scrollview, including a videoview (but to all effects you can consider it a normal view), which has a fullscreen button. What I would like is the fullscreen button to trigger the videoview view to go fullscreen.

What I am having trouble with is getting the videoview view, and "reassigning" its layout params to fill the whole screen.

All I would want is the videoview to "move" from its position in the linearlayout <- ScrollView <- ConstraintLayout where I can easily set it to full screen.

This is not about hiding system bars, or immersive features, I'm only talking about rellocating a view dynamically, just like a Youtube video does when you press full screen. Orientation change is not an issue.

Comment: Have you tried using MotionLayout?

Comment: Hadn't heard of it, but after a quick skim read I don't think it will help, "MotionLayout will only provide its capabilities for its direct children" - and here the issue is the videoview is inside a linear layout, inside a scrollview --- or have you used it in a similar way before?